# Forbid URLs if user not logged in

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, authentication

I have a web application which requires username and password authentication. If a user hasn't logged in then the system must stop users accessing URLs.

For example URL below should be forbidden so the user cannot open/download PDF file. URL should be accessible only if user logged in.

```
http(s)://database.mysite.com/files/whatever.pdf
```

Is there any way of doing this especially with `.htaccess`?

Thanks

Comment: http basic auth? just put the PW protection on that /files dir and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed folder outside of webroot and am using a file called download.php to first validate login and read the content of the file to be downloaded. It wasn't designed this way before by developers.

```
require_once 'validate_login.php';

function download($filename)
{
    $path = '/var/www/vhosts/forms/';

    if (file_exists($path . $filename))
    {
        //echo $filename . ' exists';
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename= ' . $filename);
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        readfile($path . $filename);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $filename . ' doesnt exist';
    }
}

$filename = $_GET['filename'];

download($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is add the following into a htaccess in your files folder:

```
deny from all
```

Then, have a PHP script which is your download handler - e.g. www.mysite.com/downloads.php?file=whatever.pdf.  The php script can then handle whether the user has the correct access or not.